# Laravel Heroku SQS worker sending empty messages continously, error on countable

Tags: laravel, heroku, amazon-sqs

I'm currently running my Laravel 5.4 app on Heroku and using SQS for our queue. My procfile looks like this:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
worker: php artisan queue:work sqs --tries=3 --daemon
```

This has been working great and consistently processes all items in the queue. However, I noticed an error that is coming through fairly consistently every minute:
[View Bugsnag Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkLVK.png).
The main error is: `ErrorExceptionartisan queue:work sqs --tries=3
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

On the SQS side, I noticed that CloudWatch is tracking almost 100 empty receives every minute ([CloudWatch Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmf5s.png)). I have basic understanding of Laravel's/SQS system so I am unsure if these are related, and am unsure how to proceed with debugging them. Thank you for any suggestions or insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the empty messages are related, but the `count()` error is because 
PHP 7.2 added a warning if you try to count an uncountable instance. This issue has been fixed as of Laravel 5.5.25.

You either need to downgrade PHP to 7.1, or you need to upgrade Laravel to at least 5.5.25.